# Python - Key of max value in nested dict, generalization

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key, max

I would like to know how we can return the key value of nested dicts. The case of dict of dict (case 1) has already been answer elsewhere, but I do not manage to generalise

Case 1: dict of dict

```
dict = {'key1': {'subkey1': value11, 'subkey2': value12, ...}
        'key2': {'subkey1': value21, 'subkey2': value22, ...}
        ...}
```

In order to get the key with the maximum 'subkey1' value I would do:

```
max(dict, key=lambda x: dict[x].get('subkey1'))
```

Case 2:

```
dict = {'key1': 
         {'subkey1': 
           {'subsubkey1': value111, 'subsubkey2': value112, ...}}
        'key2': 
          {'subkey2': 
            {'subsubkey1': value211, 'subsubkey2': value212, ...}}}
        ...}
```

So my questions are:

- How can we generalise the formula of case1? if I want the 'key' of a maximum 'subsubkey'?
- In terms of performance, would another solution be more efficient than a 1-line formula?

Thank you for your help and contribution

Comment: what is the result you expect?

Comment: I would like the 'key' of the max subsubkey1. Let's say value111=111 and so on. In this example it would be key2

Comment: Have you tried using recursion to get from `key >> subkey >> subsubkey` to an arbitrarily long nesting structure to `sub...subkey`? This way you get as deep as you need into the subdicts, and then return the 'root' key at the end

Comment: Yes, the point would be to avoid recursion, if possible. But what about performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you know the path of the nested key. Then one possible view of case 2 is:

```
((d.get(key)).get(subkey1)).get(subsubkey1)
```

You want to apply function `get` in a cumulative way, notice that `get` can be exchanged with the operator `[]`, so the above line can also be seen this way:

```
((d[key])[subkey1])[subsubkey1]
```

This is what the function [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) does, from the documentation:

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence,
>   from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
>   For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
>   ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and
>   the right argument, y, is the update value from the sequence.

So you can nest your calls in the following way:

```
from functools import reduce

d = {'key1': {'subkey1': {'subsubkey1': 1, 'subsubkey2': 2}},
     'key2': {'subkey1': {'subsubkey1': 2, 'subsubkey2': 3}}}


def value(first_key, di=None, path=None):
    lst = [di, first_key] + path
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], lst)

p = ['subkey1', 'subsubkey1']

print(max(d, key=lambda k: value(k, d, p)))
```

**Output**

```
key2
```

The generalization of `key=` comes from the `value` function. Basically the functions receives a the top level key, the dictionary and the paths of keys, then using reduce applies the call in a cumulative way.

**UPDATE**

In a more generalized manner if you have different paths to the `'sub...subkey'` for each of the top keys `['key1', 'key2', ...]` you could use a dictionary of paths for each key in the following way:

```
d = {'key1': {'subkey1': {'subsubkey1': 1, 'subsubkey2': 2}},
     'key2': {'subkey2': {'subsubkey1': 2, 'subsubkey2': 3}}}


paths = {
    'key1': ['subkey1', 'subsubkey1'],
    'key2': ['subkey2', 'subsubkey1']
}

print(max(d, key=lambda k: value(k, d, paths[k])))
```

**Output**

```
key2
```

Note that the `value` function remains the same only the path for each key is different. Also this solution gives you the added value of different path lengths for each top key.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed answer, I really appreciate it. In order for the answer to be fully generalised, what you think would be a good solution if the subkey are different (like subkey1 and subkey2)?

Comment: @Joseph If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.

Comment: I did not know I had to mark a solution as accepted, I just voted for it. And I did thank you twice! Here is another one just for you: Thank you Daniel Mesejo